# getActivity() is null inside AlertDialog of a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-alertdialog

Why the `getActivity()` is returning null inside `AlertDialog` ?

**This is the class -**

```
Class A extends Common{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        System.out.println("the activity outside dialog.."+getActivity());

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alert.setPositiveButton("Check acitivity", 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
            int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
            System.out.println("the activity inside dialog.."+getActivity());
            }
         });
      }
}
```

**The Common class is extending fragment as -**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
Class Common extends Fragment
{
  //Some code
}
```

**And the output is -**

```
the activity outside dialog..com.testapp.main.MainActivity@42131080
the activity inside dialog..null
```

Comment: So in which method is the code and where in the fragment's lifecycle is it?

Comment: @laalto - Updated the code. It is inside the `onCreateView` method on Save button click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 Activity activity;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity=activity;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this! This can leak the activity.

Comment: @BraisGabin Then what is the solution?

Answer (score 4):

i think getActivity() inside DialogInterface is pointing to the context of dialog

```
dialog.getActivity()
```

inside your DialogInterface try changing it to :

```
A.this.getActivity();
```

**Edit** : i've checked the getActivity() inside DialogInterface and it should work just fine.

another solution might be using onAttach Callback function and get your activity Context there to be sure that your Fragment attached to the parent activity before using it in dialog. then use it instead of getActivity().

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    yourActivity = activity;
}
```

Comment: *is pointing to the context of dialog*, I guess no, otherwise he will not be able event to compile

Comment: This is still giving the same result - null.

Comment: @blackbelt : ty for mentioning that , i've checked that getActivity() inside DialogInterface should work right.

Comment: @VedPrakash : are you sure that you are not using support library?

Comment: @Arash - I am using support library - `FragmentActivity android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getActivity()`. What's the difference it will make ?

Comment: @Arash - This gives compile time error - `The method getSupportActivity() is undefined for the type A`.

Comment: @VedPrakash : my last shot might be onAttach() hope it solves the issue.without seeing whole code i don't think i can help you more.

Comment: Thanks @Arash. I upvote you as I already used Sudhi solution which is just like your latest solution.

Comment: @ArashGM onAttach() Maintaining a reference to activity can leak the whole activity.

Comment: There is no method .getActivity() inside for the dialog object.

Answer (score 1):

replace getActivity() to A.this

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(A.this);
```

Comment: Compile time error - `The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(A) is undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Why the getActivity() is returning null inside AlertDialog ?
```

That is because you are calling the getActivity() of the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` not your in fragment thus giving you null.

**solution:**

```
A.this.getActivity();
```

you need to call the reference of your class by using the `this` and call the method `getActivity()`

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    System.out.println("the activity outside dialog.."+getActivity());

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setPositiveButton("Check acitivity", 
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
        int whichButton) {
        System.out.println("the activity inside dialog.."+ A.this.getActivity());
        dialog.cancel();
        }
     });
```

Comment: getActivity returns the activity that hosts the fragment, what is the difference ?

Comment: @blackbelt he is calling it inside the anonymous class which by then calling its getactivity method which will return null

Comment: This is still giving the same result - null.

Comment: well I guess this is the concept of `closure` in java, but still I guess it is not the cause

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin - What's the difference it is making other then swiping the S.O.P. statement with `dialog.cancel()` ? I am getting null still.

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` return null until Fragment not attach to the activity.

you suppose to create object after onAttach method calls.

you can create object in `onCreateview` method for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Sudhi S and Arash's answers, I think this is a cleaner option that deals with the Activity locally to the method calling it:

```
private void showDialog() {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setTitle(R.string.my_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.my_message)
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "the activity inside dialog... " + activity);
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.show();
}
```